# How do I access a single object from JSON wih javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, siblings

I have a JSON list that comes from a table in a database with multiple siblings.

```
"PlayerNumbers":{"PlayerNumber":[
{"Section":"1","Team":"1","Direction":"N","Number":"00280149","Name":" ANSART A","Updated":"False","TimeLog":"","Processed":"False"},
{"Section":"1","Team":"1","Direction":"S","Number":"00280131","Name":"ANSART Y","Updated":"False","TimeLog":"","Processed":"False"},
{"Section":"1","Team":"2","Direction":"N","Number":"01964990","Name":" LAHAYE B","Updated":"False","TimeLog":"","Processed":"False"}]}
```

Say I need to read the "Name" key where the Section=1 and Team=2 and Direction=N.

*Edit: Of course I will work with the js parsed object*

What would be the syntax in Javascript?

Comment: Firstly, the _JSON_ you posed looks invalid. Secondly, _JSON_ is just a notation. To use it in _JavaScript_, convert it to a native _JavaScript Object_ and work with that

Comment: Are you really dealing with JSON (a **string**), or with the parsed result? And note that the given JSON is invalid, it needs `{` at the beginning and `}` at the end (or similar).

Comment: Where are you stuck? You simply look through the `PlayerNumber` array.

Comment: `json.PlayerNumbers.PlayerNumber.map(function(a){return a.Section==1 && a.Direction=="N" && a.Name;}).filter(Boolean);`

Comment: @dandavis probably also want to `.filter` before the `.map`

Comment: @PaulS.: i filter after (to avoid an extra custom function) (comment updated)

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume you aren't dealing with JSON at all, but with an object tree *parsed* from JSON. And I'm going to assume what you've given is the content of an object definition, like this JSON:

```
{
    "PlayerNumbers": {
        "PlayerNumber": [
            {
                "Section": "1",
                "Team": "1",
                "Direction": "N",
                "Number": "00280149",
                "Name": " ANSART A",
                "Updated": "False",
                "TimeLog": "",
                "Processed": "False"
            },
            {
                "Section": "1",
                "Team": "1",
                "Direction": "S",
                "Number": "00280131",
                "Name": "ANSART Y",
                "Updated": "False",
                "TimeLog": "",
                "Processed": "False"
            },
            {
                "Section": "1",
                "Team": "2",
                "Direction": "N",
                "Number": "01964990",
                "Name": " LAHAYE B",
                "Updated": "False",
                "TimeLog": "",
                "Processed": "False"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So having parsed the JSON, you'll have an object with a `PlayerNumbers` property, which refers to an object with a `PlayerNumber` property, which refers to an array of objects with the information you want.

So you loop through the array until you find the first matching entry (assuming you only want the first one):

```
var name;
obj.PlayerNumbers.PlayerNumber.some(function(entry) {
    if (entry.Section == "1" && Team == "2" && entry.Direction == "N") {
        name = entry.Name;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

If you want **all** of the matches:

```
var names = obj.PlayerNumbers.PlayerNumber.filter(function(entry) {
    return (entry.Section == "1" && Team == "2" && entry.Direction == "N");
}).map(function(entry) { return entry.Name; });
```

---

Both of the above use ES5 features of `Array` missing on outdated engines. If you need to support outdated engines, all of the above can be "shimmed" or "polyfilled," a search should turn up the necessary shims/polyfills.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to summarize the question and giving such a precise answer, you've made my day :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
var playersObject = { 
    "PlayerNumbers": {
    "PlayerNumber": [{
        "Section": "1",
        "Team": "1",
        "Direction": "N",
        "Number": "00280149",
        "Name": " ANSART A",
        "Updated": "False",
        "TimeLog": "",
        "Processed": "False"
    }, {
        "Section": "1",
        "Team": "1",
        "Direction": "S",
        "Number": "00280131",
        "Name": "ANSART Y",
        "Updated": "False",
        "TimeLog": "",
        "Processed": "False"
    }, {
        "Section": "1",
        "Team": "2",
        "Direction": "N",
        "Number": "01964990",
        "Name": " LAHAYE B",
        "Updated": "False",
        "TimeLog": "",
        "Processed": "False"
    }]
    }
};

   function getParticularPlayer(section, team, direction) {
     return playersObject.PlayerNumbers.PlayerNumber.filter(function(player) {
            return (player.Section===section && player.Team===team && player.Direction===direction); 
     });
   }
```

Now, you can use

```
   var results = getParticularPlayer("1","1","N");
```

It will return you array of matching players. If your sure that always only one player is returned, you can use `results[0]`.